# How sync linux nodejs repo with master repo in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I´d like to sync my local linux repo server with remote bitbucket repo.

I am getting the next message:

```
luiz@vmi548446:/home/luiz/nuxt-iclindoctor-server$ sudo git pull
Password for 'https://aaae@bitbucket.org':
remote: Enumerating objects: 19, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 12 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (12/12), done.
From https://bitbucket.org/jwese/xxx
   829c700..7010ecf  master     -> origin/master
Updating 829c700..7010ecf
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        package-lock.json
        package.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

How could I solve it? I have no problem if the package.json will be overwritten

Comment: The second last line of the printout suggests committing first

Comment: But, I´d like overwrite all files in my local repo

Comment: You can use git reset to *delete* changes since last commit. Be sure that you want this before attempting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Please+commit+your+changes+or+stash+them+before+you+merge